# localhost: network name not found

Tags: c#, database, localhost

I'm doing database unit testing and I'm trying to write data to files via localhost, but I'm getting the error `Exception occurred: The network name cannot be found`. I have a byte array that I want to put in a text file like so:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(outputFilePath, res);
```

Where `res` is the byte array and `outputFilePath` is a string assigned as `"\\localhost\InterfaceFiles\Requirements.txt"`.

All the documentation I can find on the data types and operators indicate this should work. Anyone have an idea why it isn't? The file `Requirements.txt` doesn't exist yet, but `WriteAllBytes` should create it in that case.

edit: unchecked "trustworthy" in the Visual Studio database settings.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `localhost` with your actual PC name; the computer host name which you get by running `hostname` command under command prompt.

```
"\\PC_NAME\InterfaceFiles\Requirements.txt"
```

Comment: @Rahul: localhost should be resolved. My guess is the backslash in the literal.

Answer (score 0):

Check the string assignment, I mean the string literal. If it contains single backslashes, then it should preceded by @. If no @ then all backslashes should be doubled like:

```
 @"\\host\path\filename.any"
 // or 
"\\\\host\\path\\filename.any"
```

Comment: It's currently assigned as `private const string OutputPath = @"\\localhost\InterfaceFiles\";`

(and then concatenated with `"Requirements.txt"`)

Comment: Just tried using `"\\\\localhost\\InterfaceFiles\\"` for the sake of consistency, but no luck there either.

Comment: 1) please open a command promt an execute: ping \\localhost   what do you see? (OK, I see the message) then try to just type in the command prompt: c:>\\localhost\InterfaceFiles\ then an folder should open. If not what is the error message?

Comment: "Ping request could not find host \\localhost. What could cause that?

Comment: Diagnose, if the localhost resolves to the ip:127.0.0.1. It is safe no need to worry. Ping is the most basic IP diagnostic tool

Comment: Just for the sake of diganostics in C# try this: @"\\127.0.0.1\InterfaceFiles\Requirements.txt".

Comment: Same error. Could there be some software I'm not aware of preventing my localhost from being accessed (even by itself)?

Comment: I'm thinking there could be something wrong with my local sql server. I'll check it out later. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Maybe a firewall or ip filter may cause something similar. (one correction: ping \\localhost shouldnot work because localhost is not a netbios name. however ping localhost name resolving (dns) should work from the host file.

Comment: Problem solved. Visual Studio was set to only communicate with "trustworthy" databases.

Comment: if you found yourself, you should post an answer with your solution. This will help future visitors